# Unable to use Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic Mouse in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, mouse, wireless-mouse

Recently as soon as I connect the dongle of my [Microsoft mouse](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/mice/sculpt-ergonomic-mouse/l6v-00001) to my laptop, the explorer of Windows 10 starts to behave strangely, such that I can't click any opened windows anymore and I have to unplug the dongle and restart the laptop in order to fix it. Uninstalling and installing the driver was not beneficial.

I think as soon as I connect the Microsoft mouse to the PC no more click events will be sent to applications, even when I change the mouse to another one, the only solution would be restarting the PC.

I tested several PCs and operating systems and the problem existed on all of them.

Comment: Have you tried a different computer?  It sounds like the mouse is malfunctioning.

Comment: @Ramhound Not different computer because I don't have, but different account. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the wrong driver was installed.  Download the software directly from Microsoft's [website](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/mice/sculpt-ergonomic-mouse/l6v-00001) and install it.  This might force the proper driver to be installed, assuming that is the issue.

Comment: Nothing changed :(

Comment: @saeed If installing the correct software doesnt work, not does it work on any other computer, then most likely the hardware is defective.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the dongle is broken and causes Windows to freeze.

I suggest returning the mouse (and dongle) or asking for an exchange.

Comment: I bought it a couple of years ago, So it couldn't be exchanged.

Comment: A mouse doesn't last forever, although here it's probably the dongle.